# Cannot delete object using Amazon S3 PHP SDK. What are the possible reasons?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I am using [official PHP SDK of Amazon S3](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php) with [official service provider for laravel](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel). I am using version 3. The following is my code for deleting my target object:

```
$client = AWS::createClient('s3');

$result = $client->deleteObject(array(
    'Bucket' => self::$bucketName,
    'Key'    => $dest
));

return $result;
```

And here is the return message:

```
Model Data
----------
Data can be retrieved from the model object using the get() method of the
model (e.g., `$result->get($key)`) or "accessing the result like an
associative array (e.g. `$result['key']`). You can also execute JMESPath
expressions on the result data using the search() method.

{
    "DeleteMarker": false,
    "VersionId": "",
    "RequestCharged": "",
    "@metadata": {
        "statusCode": 204,
        "effectiveUri": "https:\/\/s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com\/my-bucket-sandbox\/testing\/NjY0MA%253D%253D1481788705.jpg",
        "headers": {
            "x-amz-id-2": "UXlVnYeU0ID07N58C20G7yh5aKIdu7jj2QP8Ai8MZc+ay5KjAen4NHPA2oRONIAGyJXuE\/kw+Rs=",
            "x-amz-request-id": "EBC374A27EE974FF",
            "date": "Thu, 15 Dec 2016 08:05:47 GMT",
            "server": "AmazonS3"
        },
        "transferStats": {
            "http": [
                []
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

From the DeleteMarker I know the delete action has failed, but the reason is not provided in the return message. Here are some other clues:

1. As I previously successfully uploaded the image, I guess it is not because of permission problem.
2. And I guess I should have created my client with correct connection, else the upload should have failed.
3. It returns 404 when the key (or path?) of the image is wrong. As I receive 204 this time, I guess it is not because the key is wrong.

Any suggestion on what are the possible reasons?

Comment: `*"From the DeleteMarker I know the delete action has failed*"` Not necessarily.  Have you confirmed that the object has really not been deleted (via the console)?  Is versioning enabled on this bucket? Also, for the example here, what is the object key?  Was it `testing/NjY0MA%3D%3D1481788705.jpg` or was it `testing/NjY0MA==1481788705.jpg`?  Assuming the delete has indeed failed, this looks like a case of double-url-escaping is causing you to try to delete the wrong key, because the two are not as equivalent as they might appear.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot You are correct that it is the problem of special character. I didn't actually solve this, but to change the file name (or should be key name?) during my upload and that solve the problem. Maybe you should try to extend it to an answer so that I can mark it as a correct answer?